# Google managed certificate

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

Do I need apply Google managed certificate for each prefix of domain as in the following?

```
socket.flytime.io
api.flytime.io
flytime.io
www.flytime.io
```

As it seems like certificate for `flytime.io` can't be used for `api.flytime.io`.

Also, does api.flytime.io belong to domain of flytime.io, or are they totally separated domains?

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs you can apply multiple domain names to a single certificate - have you tried that?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, flytime.io and api.flytime.io, does api.flytime.io belong to domain of flytime.io, or are they totally separated domains?

Comment: I *suspect* you need to list them separately. There may be some kind of wildcarding option, but I haven't tried it - and with only four domains to sort out, I'd probably list them all separately.

Answer (score 2):

A wildcard SSL certificate would usually need to match `flytime.io` + `*.flytime.io`.

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - flytime.io
    - *.flytime.io
```

If the sub-domain wildcard doesn't work, adding them individually might be the only option.

Source: [Setting up a Google-managed certificate](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#setting_up_a_google-managed_certificate).